Tying TPS736 LDO EN Pin to Vin
I want to use the TPS736 LDO for powering my custom STM32 Dev Board where I use a USB-C connector configured for 5V. I want to tie the EN pin to Vin however on page 14 on the datasheet it says:

7.3.3 Enable Pin and Shutdown The enable pin (EN) is active high and is compatible with standard TTL-CMOS levels. VEN below 0.5 V (max)
turns the regulator off and drops the GND pin current to approximately
10 nA. When EN is used to shutdown the regulator, all charge is
removed from the pass transistor gate, and the output ramps back up to
a regulated VOUT (see Figure 19).
When shutdown capability is not
required, EN can be connected to VIN. However, the pass gate may not
be discharged using this configuration, and the pass transistor may be
left on (enhanced) for a significant time after VIN has been removed.
This scenario can result in reverse current flow (if the IN pin is low
impedance) and faster ramp times upon power-up. In addition, for VIN
ramp times slower than a few milliseconds, the output may overshoot
upon power-up.

How can I ensure that V_EN is driven low before V_in? Do I add a few hundred milliohm resistor to V_in? Does this matter at all?
